# MVC 4 web api that consumes WCF Services

Tags: wcf, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to know if any of you knows how to consume wcf services from MVC 4 web API.
I know it might sound crazy but I have to have them both in the same solution, that's why I need to know if anyone here can provide me with some tutorial or **some more detailed explanation**.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

- generate your proxy class using your wcf service contract
- call the proxy class from your web api to access the wcf service.
- or make use of Castle Windsor WCF facility and let it create the client on the fly for you.
  http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=WCF-Integration-Facility&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1